# PayPal SandBox PLATFORM error 589009

Tags: ios6, runtime-error, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to get my IOS6 app to make payments to PayPal's sandbox but there seems to be some problem with the Beta release that I am using. I have included the PayPal-iOS-SDK-1.0.4 and have configured the environment to be PayPalEnvironmentSandbox and then I have added the credentials from my developer account as seen below:

```
if (payment.processable)
{
    [PayPalPaymentViewController setEnvironment:self.environment];
    NSString *customerId = [[[GlobalVariables sharedInstance] userAccount] objectForKey:@"email"];

    PayPalPaymentViewController *paymentViewController = [[PayPalPaymentViewController alloc]
        initWithClientId:kPayPalClientId 
        receiverEmail:kPayPalReceiverEmail
        payerId:customerId 
        payment:payment
        delegate:self];

    paymentViewController.hideCreditCardButton = !self.acceptCreditCards;
    [self presentViewController:paymentViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The kPayPalClientId is the Client ID from the Rest API Credentials page and the kPayPalReceiverEmail is my PayPal account (which in this case is a Swedish account).

But when I run this against the Sandbox environment i just get PLATFORM error 589009.
But if I change the kPayPalReceiverEmail to a dummy one like: @"YOUR_PAYPAL_EMAIL@yourdomain.com" it works, but then the payment is no longer connected to my account (the amount seems to be drawn from my buyeraccount but no money ends up in my recieveraccount). So when I try to verify the payment it can't be done.

So what is the problem here you think?

Comment: what is the email address of your swedish sandbox account?

Comment: I have tried with my paypal-account (which I use to log on to developer.paypal.com): Mikael.Nyborg@gmail.com and sandbox account: Mikael.Nyborg-facilitator@gmail.com and none of them is working.

I am a little confused on which one of these accounts to use because in the documentation is only says the following:

    You need two credentials:
    clientId: Available on the PayPal developer site.
    receiverEmail: Your PayPal account email address

But there is no information on what the receiverEmail is? Is it the account I log on with, or is it the account that is created for me?

Comment: I tried your facilitator account was able to send you a payment via iOS SDK.

Comment: Thank you Dennis for the try and I see your payment in my sandbox. I tried again with the same code and credentials today and it Worked now !!!! I have done nothing to the configuration so the problem must have been in the sandbox environment in Paypals servers.

Comment: i have created an account on Paypal and a sandbox account too. When I am testing for NoNetworkEnvironment evrything is working fine. But when I am testing for Sandbox environment. I am not able to login with any account other than the sandbox one and with it also there is this 589009 error that I get.

So I need to add the credit card details on my sandbox account